# Batch fc not recognized when inside for-loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, compare

I'm a batch beginner. I would like to compare two text files inside for-loop using *fc*. I wrote the following code:

```
for %%i in (*) do (
    fc foo.txt %%i
)
```

I get the error :

```
'fc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I do it outside the loop, everything works. What's the problem here?

Comment: The only reason I can think of off the top of my head is that you changed the value of the `%PATH%` variable somehow.

Comment: If this is only part of your overall code please post the entire script.

Comment: Oh yeah, I changed `%path%` in the script, thanks a lot.

Comment: That is one reason why I call in my batch file standard windows console applications always with full path and with file extension, i.e. `%SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe`. I have seen many issues caused by `PATH` "corruption", but I have never seen that somebody modified `SystemRoot` environment variable.

Comment: Going forward please post all your code in your question. Saves a lot of time and hassle especially when you are new to batch files.

Comment: @Squashman - check that - we frequently do not want all the code. Rather we want a complete example that clearly demonstrates the problem. Ideally the posted code should have the minimum amount necessary to show the problem. The OP's posted code was incomplete because it did not have enough code to demonstrate the problem.